Starvation in the Implementation of Mutual Exclusion using Machine Language Instructions
This relates to the possibility of starvation when mutual exclusion is implemented using special machine language instructions. If multiple threads are competing to enter a critical section, faster processes may deprive slower processes from entry into critical section for ever and hence the starvation.
Isn't it the issue related to short term scheduler? It seems that it is not the relative speeds of the processes but rather the scheduling algorithm that may drive a process into starvation.
The image of excerpt from the text of William Stallings on Operating Systems says that "the selection of a waiting process is arbitrary". That's confusing me. Why it is arbitrary?Excerpt from the text Operating Systems by William Stallings Why it's not decision of scheduler?
In fact, this is a theoretical part of the course and relates to conceptual understanding of the stuff on Operating Systems.
